# Stuck on End of Proving Bonferroni Inequality

Tags: probability

An exercise asks me to prove "Bonferroni Inequality" and states it in the form of $$P\left( {A \cap B} \right) \ge 1 - P\left( {{A^C}} \right) - P\left( {{B^C}} \right)$$
I've searched a lot of old questions related to this and all of them seem to do some crazy math abstraction and reasoning (for my level, of course), so I just tried to do it with the "tools" I have myself.

I did the following:

$$\eqalign{
  & P\left( {A \cup B} \right) = P\left( A \right) + P\left( B \right) - P\left( {A \cap B} \right)  \cr 
  & P\left( {A \cup B} \right) - P\left( A \right) = P\left( B \right) - P\left( {A \cap B} \right)  \cr 
  & P\left( {{A^C}} \right) = P\left( B \right) - P\left( {A \cap B} \right) \cr} $$Adding $-1$ to each side yields
$$\eqalign{
  & P\left( {{A^C}} \right) - 1 = P\left( B \right) - 1 - P\left( {A \cap B} \right)  \cr 
  & P\left( {{A^C}} \right) - 1 =  - P\left( {{B^C}} \right) - P\left( {A \cap B} \right)  \cr 
  & P\left( {A \cap B} \right) = 1 - P\left( {{A^C}} \right) -  - P\left( {{B^C}} \right) \cr} $$
I don't know how to go from there ($=$) to the inequality I need. I'm assuming it's somethings obvious that I missed but I don't know how to bring it in.
On a side note, the question also asks me to generalize it for more than two sets... Is it doable following this path I chose?

Comment: $P(B) - P(A\cap B)$ is $P(B\setminus A)$, that usually is different from $P(A^C)$. We have $P(A^C) = 1 - P(A)$.

Comment: To elaborate and to change notation a bit, $P(B)-P(A\cap B) = P(B\cap A^c)$, seen directly from [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), which may or may not be equal to $P(A^c)$

Comment: Oops too late to edit... I'll post my comment again. Use @DanielFischer's comment to re-write the right-hand side. Rearrange it, and use the fact that $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$. Finally, use the fact that probabilities are always bounded above by $1$.

Comment: That being said, I think I see that you attempted to simplify $P(A\cup B)-P(A)$ into $P(A^c)$ rather than trying to simplify $P(B)-P(A\cap B)$ into $P(A^c)$.  Both will simplify into $P(B\cap A^c)$, also written as $P(B\setminus A)$.  You seem to have been thinking of $P(\Omega)-P(A)=1-P(A)=P(A^c)$ rather than $P(A\cup B)-P(A)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIRST APPROACH**

The given inequality is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A\cap B) \geq 1 - \textbf{P}(A^{c}) - \textbf{P}(B^{c}) \Longleftrightarrow \textbf{P}(A^{c}) + \textbf{P}(B^{c}) \geq 1 - \textbf{P}(A\cap B) = \textbf{P}(A^{c}\cup B^{c})
\end{align*}

Thus the problem is reduced to prove that the following inequality holds
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A) + \textbf{P}(B) \geq \textbf{P}(A\cup B)
\end{align*}

which is true indeed. In fact, we have
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A) + \textbf{P}(B) \geq \textbf{P}(A) + \textbf{P}(B) - \textbf{P}(A\cap B) = \textbf{P}(A\cup B)
\end{align*}

**SECOND APPROACH**

The inequality about to be proven is known as the Fréchet-Hoeffding inequality. It is stated as follows
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A\cap B) \geq \max\{\textbf{P}(A) + \textbf{P}(B) - 1,0\}
\end{align*}
Indeed, we have
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A\cup B) = \textbf{P}(A) + \textbf{P}(B) - \textbf{P}(A\cap B) \leq 1 \Longleftrightarrow \textbf{P}(A\cap B) \geq \textbf{P}(A) + \textbf{P}(B) - 1
\end{align*}

Since $\textbf{P}(A\cap B)\geq 0$, the claimed result holds. Based on it, we get
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A\cap B) \geq \textbf{P}(A) + \textbf{P}(B) - 1 = (1 - \textbf{P}(A^{c})) + (1 - \textbf{P}(B^{c})) - 1 = 1 - \textbf{P}(A^{c}) - \textbf{P}(B^{c})
\end{align*}
and the proposed inequality holds.

**GENERALIZATION FOR MORE THAN TWO SETS**

First of all, lets us consider the generalized version of the inequality:
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A_{1}\cap A_{2}\cap\ldots\cap A_{n}) \geq 1 - \textbf{P}(A^{c}_{1}) - \ldots - \textbf{P}(A^{c}_{n})
\end{align*}

This inequality is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A^{c}_{1}) + \textbf{P}(A^{c}_{2}) + \ldots + \textbf{P}(A^{c}_{n}) \geq 1 - \textbf{P}(A_{1}\cap A_{2}\cap\ldots\cap A_{n}) = \textbf{P}(A^{c}_{1}\cup A^{c}_{2}\cup\ldots A^{c}_{n})
\end{align*}
that is the same as
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A_{1}) + \textbf{P}(A_{2}) + \ldots + \textbf{P}(A_{n}) \geq \textbf{P}(A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup \ldots\cup A_{n})
\end{align*}
which can be proven using the principle of mathematical induction.

Answer (score 1):

Not as an answer, but in order to offer an easier way. The proof of inequality is quite simple: 
$$\mathbb P(A\cap B) = 1-\mathbb P(A^c\cup B^c) \geq 1-(\mathbb P(A^c)+\mathbb P(B^c))$$
The first equality is due to $(A\cap B)^c=A^c\cup B^c$, and the second inequality is since $$\mathbb P(X\cup Y)=\mathbb P(X)+\mathbb P(Y) - \mathbb P(X\cap Y)\leq \mathbb P(X)+\mathbb P(Y).$$